# Remove namespace and convert string to date in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an Input xml,using the below DateTransform.xslt I am able to change the StartDate under Input Element from string to Date format,I also want to add the same StartDate(in Date format) to all the account Elements.I also want to remove namespaces.I am new to XSLT I tried the below transformation but not getting the required output could someone please help me on this

Input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Input>
  <BankName>SBI</BankName>
  <BranchCode>03</BranchCode>
  <StartDate>20080331</StartDate>
  <Account>
    <AccountName>ABC</AccountName>
    <AccountNumber>123</AccountNumber>
    <Balance>-0000123345</Balance>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <AccountName>PQR</AccountName>
    <AccountNumber>234</AccountNumber>
    <Balance>000349015</Balance>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <AccountName>XYZ</AccountName>
    <AccountNumber>345</AccountNumber>
    <Balance>0949710</Balance>
  </Account>
</Input>
```

DateTransform.xslt

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Input">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::Account)][not(self::StartDate)]"/>
           <xsl:variable name="in"><xsl:value-of select="StartDate"/> 
           </xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="date" select="xs:date(concat(
            substring($in,1,4),'-',
            substring($in,5,2),'-',
            substring($in,7,2)))"/>
           <StartDate>
              <xsl:value-of select="format-date($date,'[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]')"/>
           </StartDate>
            <Accounts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Account"/>
            </Accounts>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Account">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
             <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::StartDate"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

Output.xml

```
<Input>
  <BankName>SBI</BankName>
  <BranchCode>03</BranchCode>
  <StartDate 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">31/03/2008</StartDate>
  <Accounts xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Account>
        <AccountName>ABC</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>123</AccountNumber>
        <Balance>-0000123345</Balance>
        <StartDate>20080331</StartDate>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <AccountName>PQR</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>234</AccountNumber>
        <Balance>000349015</Balance>
        <StartDate>20080331</StartDate>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <AccountName>XYZ</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>345</AccountNumber>
        <Balance>0949710</Balance>
        <StartDate>20080331</StartDate>
    </Account>
 </Accounts>
</Input>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Input>
   <BankName>SBI</BankName>
   <BranchCode>03</BranchCode>
   <StartDate>31/03/2008</StartDate>
   <Accounts>
      <Account>
        <AccountName>ABC</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>123</AccountNumber>
        <Balance>-0000123345</Balance>
        <StartDate>31/03/2008</StartDate>
      </Account>
      <Account>
        <AccountName>PQR</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>234</AccountNumber>
        <Balance>000349015</Balance>
        <StartDate>31/03/2008</StartDate>
      </Account>
      <Account>
        <AccountName>XYZ</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>345</AccountNumber>
        <Balance>0949710</Balance>
        <StartDate>31/03/2008</StartDate>
       </Account>
   </Accounts>
</Input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="new-date">
    <xsl:variable name="startDate" select="/Input/StartDate" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($startDate, 7, 2), substring($startDate, 5, 2), substring($startDate, 1, 4)" separator="/"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="StartDate">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$new-date"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Account">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <StartDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="$new-date"/>    
        </StartDate>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Added:**

A shorter way to reformat the date:

```
<xsl:variable name="new-date" select="replace(/Input/StartDate, '(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})', '$3/$2/$1')"/>
```

Comment: -Thanks a lot,it helped me

Comment: In the regex you can simplify `(.{2})` to `(..)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute on `xsl:stylesheet` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
```